# Need help to find replacement for power mosfet IRF7303

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, dc-dc-converter, powermosfet

I have to design a voltage regulator circuit using [DC-DC controller MAX1655.](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1652-MAX1655.pdf)
Required voltage output from the circuit is [3.3V at 2A (circuit is shown at page 10 of datasheet).](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1652-MAX1655.pdf)

According to the datasheet for [MAX1655 (at page no- 11)](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1652-MAX1655.pdf) i have to use [IRF7303](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf7303.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355f1be991afa) or NDS8936 as mosfet in the circuit.

After looking up on the internet i found that NDS8936 is obsolete/not manufactured anymore.But i am unable to confirm whether [IRF7303](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf7303.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355f1be991afa) is locally available at my place.

Questions:
1)I would like to know if any functionally equivalent mosfet for IRF7303 exists so that i can use in this circuit(for output 3.3V at 2A)?

2)Does the complete  circuit using DC-DC controller MAX1655 work as a voltage regulator(Can it handle changes in input voltage)?

Comment: @LeonHeller The MAX1655 already cost me about 20$ for 2 unit and i do not want to spend a lot for a mosfet . In addition to that, Digikey''s shipping fee is too much even if its for a 1$ item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IRF7303 is available [here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-arrays/289?k=IRF7303&k=&pkeyword=IRF7303&pv1989=0&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25) on DigiKey. I don't know if that works for you since you said you want it locally...

> 1)I would like to know if any functionally equivalent mosfet for IRF7303 exists so that i can use in this circuit(for output 3.3V at 2A)?

If you were to use a different MOSFET, page 22 of the datasheet gives you some guidelines you should follow:

[image]

Based on that, you should be able to find a suitable Mosfet on DigiKey o somewhere else. For example, the [SH8K1](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Rohm%20PDFs/SH8K1.pdf) (which I found on a really quick search, didn't give too much thought to all the tradeoffs you may want to consider) seems like a good choice. This is [it](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/rohm-semiconductor/SH8K1TB1/SH8K1TB1CT-ND/2357481) on DigiKey. There *tons* of options, this is not meant to be a unique solution—just to give it some context.

The SH8K1 is comparable to the IRF7303. It has lower gate charge specs than the IRF7303 (the datasheet for your voltage controller recommends < 70nC). Also, the current and voltage specs for the transistors are similar—and they come in a similar package (dual N channel mosfets).

> 2)Does the complete circuit using DC-DC controller MAX1655 work as a voltage regulator(Can it handle changes in input voltage)?

Yes. On page 11 it says that the range for your settings (3.3V @ 2A)  is between 4.75V to 28V. The upper limit is depends on the Mosfet you choose (e.g 30V) like the IRF7303 and SH8K1.

Comment: The MAX1655 already cost me about 20$ for 2 unit and i do not want to spend a lot for a mosfet . In addition to that, Digikey''s shipping fee is too much even if its for a 1$ item.This is why i wanted to find  alternative mosfet which maybe available at local shops.

Comment: @Mrchief how about you go to the local shop and *see* what they currently have available? Then choose what's best of whatever is available...

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. I will do as you have explained.

Comment: @Mrchief you are welcome. Andy's answer is really good, too. It gives a more general insight.

Comment: @Yes i have upvoted. But unfortunately i am unable to accept more than 1 answer. Plus, you answered both of my questions too. I have one more doubt. Does International Rectifier
1/2 IRF7303  mean that only half part of a single IRF7303 is used in that point in the circuit?

Comment: @Mrchief where does it say that? My guess is that 1/2 of that means only using a *single* transistor. The IRF7303 has two internal N-ch mosfets inside.

Comment: It is mentioned  At page 11 of datasheet under the  column named "3.3V at 2A" and row named "Q1 HIGH SIDE MOSFET". Please check it and reply.

Comment: @Mrchief Yeah, that's what it means: The IRF7303 has two NMOS transistors inside. 1/2 means one of them. The DC-DC controller uses two transistors (high side and low side). They just break it down and tell you that the high side and low side each correspond to one of the transistors in the IRF7303.

Answer (score 2):

Virtually all enhancement mode MOSFETs are functionally equivalent but some will be better choices than others. Try and find a MOSFET with these performance characteristics: -

- The same or lower on-resistance for a given range of gate voltages likely to be applied in the MAXIM circuit described on page 10
- The same or higher maximum drain-source voltage rating
- The same or higher maximum drain current
- At least the same package type but double check also that the thermal resistance is at least as good
- Gate capacitance about the same as the obsolete device. +/- 50% should be OK

It may take an hour or two but when you have something you think will do the job, leave a comment with links to the old part's and the new part's data sheets for a quick double check.

Comment: Can i use two N-channel  AO4714 Mosfet instead of dual N-Channel IRF7303? Can you check their datasheets and tell me whether it will do?[AO4714 Datasheet](http://aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO4714.pdf)   [IRF7303 Datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf7303.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355f1be991afa)

Comment: The gate input capacitance for the AO part is quite high (5 nF) and may cause problems with the MAXIM chip. Try and find a MOSFET that is less than 1 nF input capacitance is my recommendation. I expect AO will have one and you can certainly sacrifice "on" resistance to get this. The AO device you chose is roughly ten times better than the IRF so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: How about [IRFZ44N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44n.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3575220b) ?

Comment: What value is Ciss? Can the maxim chip drive that Ciss adequately? What did I recommend for Ciss in my above comment?

Comment: I indeed read your previous comment. This(IRFZ44N) was the mosfet with specs closest to IRF7303 in the local shop that i asked.So i was thinking whether this would do enough

Comment: If you go through the list of MOSFETs in table 1 of the MAXIM spec and none have an input (gate source) capacitance as high as the IRFZ44 then I would worry about the choice of that MOSFET.

Answer (score 1):

Digi-Key stocks the IRF7303. You shouldn't have any problem buying them.